# Importing a p12 on Windows Server

Tags: windows, certificate

I have a weird problem with importing a p12 cert.
I created a pkcs12 cert using keytool on windows server, but when I trying import this cert I get a prompt with an error "password that is incorrect", but when I'm trying to import this cert to another windows station, the process will be completed successfully.
Regards!

edit1
If I open cert in the keystore explorer everything open correctly

Comment: Isn't it because in the "other Windows station" you're using the correct password?

Comment: I use the same password for both windows stations

Comment: How are you importing the certificate? Which version(s) of Windows are on both computers?

Comment: works on Windows 10 (19043.1110), but the destination server is windows 2016 (14393.4402)

Comment: Are you sure the password was entered correctly? Better to use clipboard to paste the password e.g. via RDP connection. Or type the password in notepad and then copy it into the password field.

Comment: yes, I tried to copy-paste the password with the same result, also, I tried to import this cert via powershell or using mmc snap-in...